# Born-Infeld term for $D$-brane low energy effective action

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, action, branes

I am trying to reproduce the Born-Infeld term for the $D$-brane action as explained in [Szabo's BUSSTEP Lectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0207142) and must admit I am utterly confused by some of the steps.

This is a long and technical question, so I first give some context, then I give my problems.
All of this can be answered easily if someone can point me to a detailed derivation of that result.

**The context**

Szabo starts with the effective bosonic open string action in the conformal gauge with the endpoints coupled to a gauge field, (7.21),
$$ 
S[x,A] =\frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'} \int d^2z \, \partial x^\mu \bar \partial x_\mu -\frac{i}{2} \int_0^{2\pi} \partial_\theta x^\mu A_\mu \Big|_{r=1}
$$
Here $\theta$ is the polar angle describing the unit disc. He then uses the background field method of separating out the zero modes $x^\mu =x_0^\mu + \xi^\mu$ and path integrating over the fluctuations $\xi$. Integrating out the bulk modes leaves a boundary path integral
$$
Z = g_s^{-1} \int d\vec{x}_0 \int \mathcal D \xi^\mu(\theta) e^{-S_b[\xi,A]} \tag{1}
$$
with the boundary action
$$
S_b[\xi,A] = \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \left[ \frac{1}{4\pi\alpha'} \xi^\mu N^{-1} \xi_\mu + iF_{\mu\nu} \xi^\mu\dot\xi^\nu  \right] \tag{2}
$$
with $N^{-1}$ the space inverse of the Green's function on the disc with Neumann boundary conditions. It is given by (7.31)
$$
N^{-1}(\theta,\theta')  = -\frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \cos [n(\theta-\theta')]  \tag{3}
$$
He expands the fluctuations in Fourier modes
$$
\xi^\mu (\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[ a_n^\mu \cos n\theta + b_n^\mu \sin n\theta\right]
$$
and then rotates the field tensor in a canonical Jordan form
$$
F_{\mu\nu} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & - f_1 & & 0 & 0 \\
f_1 &0 & & 0 & 0 \\
& & \ddots &  &  \\
0& 0 & &0&-f_{D/2}\\
0 & 0 & & f_{D/2} &0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and claims that we end up with Gaussian integrations with quadratic forms (7.35). Ignoring some coefficients these are
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a_m^{2\ell-1} & a_n^{2\ell} \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2\pi \alpha' f_\ell \\ 2\pi \alpha' f_\ell & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} a_m^{2\ell-1} \\ a_n^{2\ell} \end{pmatrix}  \tag{4}
$$
and a similar expression with the $b_n^\ell$'s.

**My questions** (4 is the most pressing one)

1. In (1) why integrate over the space coordinate $d\vec{x}_0$ only? What happened with the time coordinate
2. How do you derive the kinetic term $\xi^\mu N^{-1} \xi_\mu$ in (2)?
3. How do you prove (3)?
4. How do you derive (4)? In particular

$\quad$ (4a) The kinetic term has a triple sum (coming from two $\xi$'s and one $N^{-1}$). It leads to integrations of the form $f(n\theta)  \cos k \theta g(n\theta)$ where $f$ and $g$ can be $\cos$ or $\sin$. This gives one delta function, so we are left with a double sum. (4) has only a single sum over $n$? How is that possible?

$\quad$ (4b) The gauge field part has a $\xi^\mu \dot \xi^\nu$. The $\dot \xi^\nu$ essentially switches the $\cos$ and the $\sin$ in the Fourier expansion. The non-zero $\theta$ integrations are then over $a_m^\mu b_n^\nu  \cos (m\theta) \cos (n\theta) $ and $b_m^\mu a_n^\nu\sin (m\theta)  \sin (n\theta)$. i.e. the $a$'s and the $b$ get mixed up, whereas in (4) they are not. What did I miss?

$\quad$ (4c) How did the coefficient $i$ disappear from (2) to  (4)?

**Edit** Note added: In the meanwhile I have found [Non-linear electrodynamics from quantized strings” by E.S. Fradkin and A.A. Tseytlin](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(85)90205-9) which may contain the answers to (at least) some of these questions.